# Unable to parse json value in helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a configMap which I'm trying to template. I have this  json value in my values.yaml file and in my configmap template I'm trying to get it as is via this command.

Is there a way how to parse the json value and it would return a clean json value which i can apply into my kubernetes cluster. Thanks a lot

```
configmap.yaml
data: {{ .Values.config | toJson | quote }}

values.yaml
instance-0.json: |-
   {
     "name": nameofserver,
     "connectionType": "STANDALONE",
     "host": "IP",
     "port": 6379,
     "username": "",
     "password": "",
     "tls": {
         "useTls": false,
         "verifyServerCert": true,
         "clientAuth": false
     }

Result:

data: "{\"instance-0.json\":\"{\\n  \\\"name\\\": \\\"nameofserver\\\",\\n  \\\"connectionType\\\": \\\"STANDALONE\\\",\\n  \\\"host\\\": \\\"IP\\\",\\n  \\\"port\\\": 6379,\\n  \\\"username\\\": \\\"\\\",\\n  \\\"password\\\": \\\"\\\",\\n  \\\"tls\\\": {\\n      \\\"useTls\\\": false,\\n      \\\"verifyServerCert\\\": true,\\n      \\\"clientAuth\\\": false\\n  }\"}"
```

I tried the above and expected that it returns a clean Json file

Answer (score 1):

values.yaml

```yaml
config: 
  instance-0.json: |-
    {
      "name": nameofserver,
      "connectionType": "STANDALONE",
      "host": "IP",
      "port": 6379,
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "tls": {
          "useTls": false,
          "verifyServerCert": true,
          "clientAuth": false
      }
```

cm.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  {{- toYaml .Values.config | nindent 2 }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  instance-0.json: |-
    {
      "name": nameofserver,
      "connectionType": "STANDALONE",
      "host": "IP",
      "port": 6379,
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "tls": {
          "useTls": false,
          "verifyServerCert": true,
          "clientAuth": false
      }
```